# foreach inside a foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I have an array which contains the size of files in a folder, and then I have a list that contain the actual size. `gf.GameInformation` is a dictionary with contain a string for a filename and the current file's size. I want to loop through each element in files and check if the current element size is the same or not the same to the actual file size in `gf.GameInformation`, but this method gives me a weird result.

```
        FileInfo[] files = fileInfo.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo i in files)
        {
            foreach(var x in gf.GameInfomation)
            {
                if (i.Length != x.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.Length);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"but this method gives me a weird result."_ would you  mind telling us the problem?

Comment: What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: It is unclear what _exactly_ this should do and it looks like an XY problem. Do you mean you want to find the item in `gf.GameInformation` that corresponds to the `FileInfo i`? You don't need nested foreach loops for that.

Comment: What are the "weird results" you're seeing?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I don't see any "weirdness" unless you tell us.

Comment: Check my edit. It prints out all i.Length?

Comment: when is `i.Length` not equal to `x.Value`? Set breakpoints and step through your code. TBH I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Please provide an example of inputs and what the desired output and actual output are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want to evaluate every `gf.GameInformation` but only the one corresponding to `FileInfo i`. You could do something along the lines of

```
FileInfo[] files = fileInfo.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo i in files)
{
    if (i.Length != gf.GameInfomation[i.Name].Value)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very well @ArthurRey, but i don't quite understand this line: gf.GameInfomation[i.Name]

Comment: @LocDaiLe `gf.GameInformation` is a `Dictionnary`. This is the way to get the matching value of the `FileInfo i` you are currently looping through.

Comment: One last question. How come my code doens't work, any explanation @ArthurRey?

Comment: @LocDaiLe Note that I removed one `foreach`. What your code does is to compare each `FileInfo i` to every `gf.GameInformation x`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
FileInfo[] files = fileInfo.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo i in files)
{
   if(gf.GameInfomation[i.Name] !=i.Length ) //Do something;
}
```

or if you can use Linq

```
FileInfo[] files = fileInfo.GetFiles();
files.Where(x=>gf.GameInfomation[x.Name] !=x.Length).ToList().ForEach(
//do Something
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like i want it. But i don't quite understand this gf.GameInfomation[i.Name] @Nickthename

Comment: if gf.GameInfomation is a dictionary having the name of files as a key, you can access the actual size of the file directly using the name of file.